# fullcalendar.js select constraint

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use the eventConstraint functionality in fullcalendar.js which works perfectly with already created events.
My question is how do you constrain new events?

I was thinking of making 'selectable' false and using eventMouseover and eventMouseout to set it to true/false respectively when it hovers the constraining background event.   But the problem is that those two callbacks aren't triggered on background events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [select contraint](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectConstraint/) method. It works exactly the same that 'eventContraint' you are already using:

```
{
    start: '10:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
    end: '18:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)

    dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
    // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
    // (Monday-Thursday in this example)
}
```

Keep in mind that, as docs says:

> Only applicable when the selectable option is activated.

This will disallow the user to create new events in the constraint with a nice not-allowed cursor.

Comment: wow,   i am so sorry
I have no idea how I missed this.
I was up coding really late.